# Error When I upload any file to web server

Tags: server, wordpress

I use ubuntu 14.04, & installed everything relate web server correctly like Apache, php, MySQL, phpmyadmin/ , I am installed wordpress on Ubuntu server...
When I add image on wp post getting error message `"Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2015/07. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"`

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the permissions of your Wordpress installation are not properly set up. Try running the following commands in the root directory:

`sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
sudo chmod 660 wp-config.php`

This is an example permission setup of course. By using it, you grant users of the Wordpress site the appropriate permissions for reading and modifying the files and directories, while having to access to the configuration file of the installation.

See this page for more info: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/